# Puppet Master not serving out/reading manifests

Tags: puppet

I have a really strange issue with my Puppet Master.

I can't seem to get it to serve my manifests properly. I have installed manifests in two locations:

- `/etc/puppet/manifests/kungfumaster.mydomain.com.pp`
- `/etc/puppet/environments/production/kungfumaster.mydomain.com.pp`

Both of which contain something similar to this:

```
node "kungfumaster.mydomain.com" { 
    notify { "found the one in environments!": }
}
```

Neither of them run when I connect with my agent. The only one which is actually read appears to be `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`, which does, in fact, run:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Notify[thungs]/message: defined 'message' as 'thungs'
```

This node is defined like this:

```
node default { 
    notify { 'thungs': }
}
```

No matter how I've tried, I haven't been able to get these manifests to work properly, even when specifying a `node default` in the aforementioned files.

I'm seeing some strange logs emitted from my Puppet Master, but I'm not quite clear as to what they mean or how to solve the problem mentioned in them:

```
Jul 31 01:50:28 kungfumaster puppet-master[443]: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Jul 31 01:50:28 kungfumaster puppet-master[443]: Could not retrieve fact ipaddress
Jul 31 01:50:28 kungfumaster puppet-master[443]: TrustedInformation expected a certificate, but none was given.
```

Configuration files:

- [/etc/puppet/puppet.conf](http://pastebin.com/D8iYR2u9)
- [/usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmaster/config.ru](http://pastebin.com/HNS7Nskn) (config file for running the Puppet Master rails app)
- [/etc/nginx/nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/E2Jb39VC)
- [/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/puppetmaster](http://pastebin.com/ZnFy8S1z)

Log files:

- [/var/log/syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7910682/)
- Output of `puppet apply --onetime --no-daemonize --debug --verbose`: [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7910702/)
- Output of `puppet apply --onetime --no-daemonize --debug --verbose --environment production`: [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7910703/)

The Puppet Agent and Puppet Master are both on the exact same host.

The strange message about expecting a certificate is generated here: https://j.mp/1zxG08Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have the [`manifest` parameter](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/configuration.html#manifest) set in your `puppet.conf`, meaning it defaults to `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`.

If you instead change it to `/etc/puppet/manifests`, puppet will pull in every file in that directory.

So basically add the following to your config:

```
[main]
manifest = $manifestdir
```

*(`$manifestdir` defaults to `/etc/puppet/manifests`)*

Comment: This actually work, but when I run `puppet agent --test` on the master machine I get this warning: "Warning: Setting manifest is deprecated in puppet.conf." Any clue?

Comment: Not off hand no. I haven't been keeping up with the latest puppet releases. Best bet is to just consult the docs on the parameter and see what's going on.